# JavaFX change Text by clicking on Button

Tags: java, javafx

Following task: I want a text with the Letter `'L'` and two `Button`s, one to "increase" and one to "decrease" the letter. But only until the Letters `'A'` or `'Z'` are reached. Got to the point where I can increase/decrease the letter until the wished Letters. Only Problem: When I get to `'Z'` and then click the button to go back it increases the letter one more time to `'['`. I got the feeling that the text doesn't react properly to the button. Sorry if the description is confusing

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private Character defaultLetter = 'L';

    private Button btnred;
    private Button btngreen;
    private Text text;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        btnred = new Button();
        btnred.setText("Previous");
        btnred.getStyleClass().add("green-btn-small-font");
        btnred.setOnAction(this);
        btnred.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #E70116;");

        btngreen = new Button();
        btngreen.setText("Next");
        btngreen.getStyleClass().add("red-btn-small-font");
        btngreen.setOnAction(this);
        btngreen.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #01E736;");

        text = new Text();
        text.setText(String.valueOf(defaultLetter));
        text.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial;");
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(text);
        pane.setLeft(btngreen);
        pane.setRight(btnred);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setTitle("Hausaufgabe 1");
        stage.setX(400);
        stage.setY(200);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }


    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if ((event.getSource() == btnred) && defaultLetter >= 'A') {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(defaultLetter--));
        }
        if ((event.getSource() == btngreen) && defaultLetter <= 'Z') {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(defaultLetter++));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your condition is `<= 'Z'`. So if it is `Z` it will increase once more. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((event.getSource() == btnred) && defaultLetter > 'A') {
    defaultLetter--;
    text.setText(String.valueOf(defaultLetter));
}
if ((event.getSource() == btngreen) && defaultLetter < 'Z') {
     defaultLetter++;
     text.setText(String.valueOf(defaultLetter));
}
```

you need to update defaultLetter value each time

Comment: `text.setText(String.valueOf(++defaultLetter));`

Comment: Wow that was actually pretty obvious. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should read the new letter after incrementing/decrementing. Furthermore you shouldn't use the same event handler for multiple buttons, if the functionality for the possible sources is completely distinct (in your case at most one of the `if` bodys can be entered).

Also since you check before the update to the letter, you cannot allow the increment to happen, if `defaultLetter == boundChar`.

Better do something like this:

```
ObjectProperty<Character> letter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>('L');
btnred.setOnAction(evt -> {
    char newLetter = (char) (letter.get() - 1);

    // just checking for demonstration
    // disable binding should prevent the action from triggering
    // when the following condition is false
    if (newLetter >= 'A') {
        letter.set(newLetter);
    }
});
btngreen.setOnAction(evt -> {
    char newLetter = (char) (letter.get() + 1);

    // just checking for demonstration
    // disable binding should prevent the action from triggering
    // when the following condition is false
    if (newLetter <= 'Z') {
        letter.set(newLetter);
    }
});

text.textProperty().bind(letter.asString());
btnred.disableProperty().bind(letter.isEqualTo('A'));
btngreen.disableProperty().bind(letter.isEqualTo('Z'));
```